# liquibase : generate changelogs from existing database

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible with liquibase to generate changelogs from an existing database?
I would like to generate one xml changelog per table (not every create table statements in one single changelog).

Answer (score 2):

If you look into [documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html) it looks like it generates only one changelog with many changesets (one for each table). So by default there is no option to generate changelogs per table.

Answer (score 0):

While [`liquibase generate-changelog`](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) still doesn't support splitting up the generated changelog, you can split it yourself.

If you're using JSON changelogs, you can do this with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq).

I created a jq filter to group the related changesets, and combined it with a Bash script to split out the contents. [See this blog post](https://williamvds.me/blog/split-liquibase-changelog/)

jq filter, `split_liquibase_changelog.jq`:

```
# Define a function for mapping a changes onto its destination file name
# createTable and createIndex use the tableName field
# addForeignKeyConstraint uses baseTableName
# Default to using the name of the change, e.g. createSequence
def get_change_group: map(.tableName // .baseTableName)[0] // keys[0];

# Select the main changelog object
.databaseChangeLog
# Collect the changes from each changeSet into an array
| map(.changeSet.changes | .[])
# Group changes according to the grouping function
| group_by(get_change_group)
# Select the grouped objects from the array
| .[]
# Get the group name from each group
| (.[0] | get_change_group) as $group_name
# Select both the group name...
| $group_name,
# and the group, wrapped in a changeSet that uses the group name in the ID and
# the current user as the author
  { databaseChangelog: {
      changeSet: {
      id: ("table_" + $group_name),
      author: env.USER,
      changes: . } } }
```

Bash:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Example: ./split_liquibase_changelog.sh schema < changelog.json

set -e -o noclobber

OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="${1:-schema}"
OUTPUT_FILE="${2:-schema.json}"

# Create the output directory
mkdir --parents "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"

# --raw-output: don't quote the strings for the group names
# --compact-output: output one JSON object per line
jq \
    --raw-output \
    --compact-output \
    --from-file split_liquibase_changelog.jq \
| while read -r group; do # Read the group name line
    # Read the JSON object line
    read -r json
    # Process with jq again to pretty-print the object, then redirect it to the
    # new file
    (jq '.' <<< "$json") \
        > "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"/"$group".json
done

# List all the files in the input directory
# Run jq with --raw-input, so input is parsed as strings
# Create a changelog that includes everything in the input path
# Save the output to the desired output file
(jq \
    --raw-input \
    '{ databaseChangeLog: [
        { includeAll:
            { path: . }
        }
     ] }' \
    <<< "$OUTPUT_DIRECTORY"/) \
    > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

If you need to use XML changesets, you can try adapting this solution using an XML tool like [XQuery](https://www.w3.org/XML/Query/) instead.